# Scraping issue: Beatifulsoup; IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape: http://www.wtatennis.com/stats. But I run into an error when I have the complete code done. Potentially I'm starting to long at this but I don't see the error and therefore can't resolve it.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("http://www.wtatennis.com/stats")
c=r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"view-content"})

#find the results, names, scores

for classes in all:

        position = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-counter views-align-center"})[0].text
        wta_name = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-lastname views-align-left"})[0].text
        current_ranking = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-current-rank views-align-center"})[0].text
        match_count = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-matchcount views-align-center"})[0].text
        aces_count = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-aces active views-align-center"})[0].text
        df_count = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-double-faults views-align-center"})[0].text
        firstserver_perc = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-first-serve-percent views-align-center"})[0].text
        firstservewon_perc = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-first-serve-won-percent views-align-center"})[0].text
        secondservewon_perc = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-second-serve-won-percent views-align-center"})[0].text


        print (position)
        print (wta_name)
        print (current_ranking)
        print (match_count)
        print (aces_count)
        print (df_count)
        print (firstserver_perc)
        print (firstservewon_perc)
        print (secondservewon_perc)
```

**Result**

> 1
>    Goerges, Julia (GER)
>   12
>   7
>   61
>   25
>    59.8 %
>    76.0 %
>
> ### 52.4 %

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-fabdb2904a0b> in <module>()
     18         current_ranking = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-current-rank views-align-center"})[0].text
     19         match_count = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-matchcount views-align-center"})[0].text
---> 20         aces_count = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-aces active views-align-center"})[0].text
     21         df_count = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-double-faults views-align-center"})[0].text
     22         firstserver_perc = classes.find_all('td',{"class":"views-field views-field-field-first-serve-percent views-align-center"})[0].text

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Don't you expect to have a better solution to serve the same purpose? It can be done using fewer lines of codes.

Comment: I think the reason he wrote his program like that is because he didn't want to parse all the columns of the table dynamically. I think he just needed specific columns from looking at way he wrote his code.

Comment: Specific columns can be parsed as well with fewer lines of codes. The way OP wrote is error prone.

Comment: Hi @SIM I'm still learning. So yes, I need to improve. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the issues I found with your code:

1. The line `all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"view-content"})` is using the find_all, which is wrong because there are multiple `div` tags with class `view-content`. I changed this line to use the `find()` function instead of the `find_all()` function
2. After fixing the issue stated in the previous bulletpoint, you will have issues specficially at the printing area(Not getting all the data, just the first record of the table you're trying to parse).

Also Note that I removed the `re` library imported in your code, as it wasn't needed.

Here is my attempt at your problem:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

c = requests.get("http://www.wtatennis.com/stats").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
c = soup.find("div", {"class": "view-content"})

position = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-counter views-align-center"})
wta_name = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-lastname views-align-left"})
current_ranking = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-current-rank views-align-center"})
match_count = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-matchcount views-align-center"})
aces_count = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-aces active views-align-center"})
df_count = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-double-faults views-align-center"})
firstserver_perc = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-first-serve-percent views-align-center"})
firstservewon_perc = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-first-serve-won-percent views-align-center"})
secondservewon_perc = c.find_all('td', {"class": "views-field views-field-field-second-serve-won-percent views-align-center"})

for i in range(0, len(position)):
    print(position[i].text)
    print(wta_name[i].text)
    print(current_ranking[i].text)
    print(match_count[i].text)
    print(aces_count[i].text)
    print(df_count[i].text)
    print(firstserver_perc[i].text)
    print(firstservewon_perc[i].text)
    print(secondservewon_perc[i].text)
    print("***************")
```

Output:

```
 1
 Goerges, Julia (GER)
12
7
61
25
 59.8 %
 76.0 %
 52.4 %
***************
 2
 Svitolina, Elina (UKR)
3
10
60
13
 60.1 %
 72.2 %
 47.5 %
***************
 3
 Wozniacki, Caroline (DEN)
1
12
58
37
 64.3 %
 71.9 %
 50.3 %
***************
 4
 Pliskova, Karolina (CZE)
5
8
53
19
 63.9 %
 71.6 %
 47.7 %
***************
 5
 Barty, Ashleigh (AUS)
16
9
50
27
 61.0 %
 67.7 %
 53.6 %
***************
 6
 Mertens, Elise (BEL)
20
10
43
35
 65.8 %
 69.1 %
 46.9 %
***************
 7
 Siniakova, Katerina (CZE)
52
8
39
31
 61.2 %
 65.5 %
 46.5 %
***************
 8
 Osaka, Naomi (JPN)
53
5
38
11
 62.5 %
 69.4 %
 44.8 %
***************
 9
 Pliskova, Kristyna (CZE)
78
5
38
17
 59.3 %
 70.4 %
 41.3 %
***************
 10
 Keys, Madison (USA)
14
6
37
17
 61.1 %
 73.9 %
 46.8 %
***************
 11
 Bertens, Kiki (NED)
28
6
35
26
 61.2 %
 70.1 %
 39.6 %
***************
 12
 Sevastova, Anastasija (LAT)
15
7
34
11
 60.2 %
 71.4 %
 47.7 %
***************
 13
 Konta, Johanna (GBR)
11
6
31
22
 65.6 %
 66.1 %
 50.0 %
***************
 14
 Halep, Simona (ROU)
2
12
30
27
 66.1 %
 68.2 %
 50.3 %
***************
 15
 Kontaveit, Anett (EST)
27
6
29
32
 63.9 %
 67.3 %
 48.3 %
***************
 16
 Strycova, Barbora (CZE)
24
10
29
25
 65.6 %
 64.4 %
 46.7 %
***************
 17
 Giorgi, Camila (ITA)
63
7
26
27
 59.3 %
 65.8 %
 48.2 %
***************
 18
 Sharapova, Maria (RUS)
41
7
26
36
 60.0 %
 70.0 %
 48.0 %
***************
 19
 Kanepi, Kaia (EST)
66
6
25
24
 56.8 %
 64.3 %
 50.3 %
***************
 20
 Watson, Heather (GBR)
75
6
25
17
 62.2 %
 65.0 %
 50.7 %
***************
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. Works like a charm! Ah I missed that. I expected only one, therefore I didn't think about it (still better to change it).

Comment: No problem @Brother17, don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your issue.
Thanks :)